# MYSQL number sorting

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that is hosting some data for an iOS app through mysql and it has some ascending and descending numbers and they are displaying as 1,11,12,13,etc.,2,20,21,22,etc.

This is the sorting function on the admin site and should translate into the JSON response for the iOS app...

```
function sortPage($pageName,$sortBy,$sortOrder, $qry = '' ){
    $getParameters = "$pageName?sortBy=$sortBy&sortOrder=$sortOrder";   
    if($catID!=''){
        $getParameters .="&catID=$catID";
    }   

    if($extraParams!=''){
        $getParameters .='&'.$extraParams;
    }

    if( $qry != '') 
        $getParameters .= $qry ;

    $url ="<a href='$getParameters' style='text-decoration:none'>";
    if($sortOrder=='ASC'){  
        $url .="<img src='".HOST."images/up-arrow.gif' width='8' height='4' border='0' />";
    }else{
        $url .="<img src='".HOST."images/down-arrow.gif' width='8' height='4' border='0'/>";
    }
    $url .="</a>";
    return $url;
}
```

Do I need to change the structure type to make it not order that way? It is currently int(11).

Comment: the sort is happening as if it's text.  so somethings off at the database.  It think's it's sorting a text field.

Comment: You said it is defined as `int(11)`. When you query the DB directly, are you getting the results properly ordered?

Comment: It is not properly ordered when I do a query for it. I am not sure if it is the database or the way that the php function is ordering it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, actually. If you perform a `select` on the table, what do you get?

Comment: You can see a screenshot of it here: http://d.pr/KiGF

Comment: And do you think an `int(11)` column can hold value `20B`? :)

Comment: ...I am assuming not :) What should the column be?

Comment: check the database again based on screenshot, it's not int(11) its likely varchar(11) or something else.  Mosty has a viable response below but if you have something like 1A and something like 100A it will still not quite be right.

Comment: Think about splitting the column into two, numeric and alpha. Then you can `order by numeric, alpha`. if you still need name field, just use `concat(numeric, alpha) as name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot I can see that is not an `int(11)` column but rather some string type.

With this query you can fool MySQL to order the ones with the number first, if that is what you want. This will work when the number is on the left part of the value:

```
select * from sections
order by 0+name, name
```

Comment: However this will destroy any speed increase you would get from indexes

Comment: @joeframbach True. Actually, doing this means: "I chose the wrong datatype or I didn't design the schema properly"

Comment: @MaxRoper No, see the screenshot you took again. The code and the data are both ok. Oh, one more thing. Also order by name so that `A` comes before `B`